# Expression Sort in Solr

Tags: solr

I am working on solr for search. I required to perform a expression sort such that :

> ORDER BY (IF(COUNTRY=1,100,0) +
>   IF(AVAILABLE=2,1000,IF(AVAILABLE=1,60,0)) + IF (DELIVERYIN IN
>   (5,6,7),100,IF (DELIVERYIN IN (80,90),50,0))) DESC

Can anyone tell me hows is this possible?

Comment: solr users.........any help on this ?

Comment: Why not just have a field with these values populated at index time so it is easier to sort of these, instead of getting the complex logic @ search time ?

Comment: the logic required run time logic as values COUNTRY=1 is based on a user whose country is 1 ,